# zsh: command not found: vim

Tags: flutter, installation

I have an issue in flutter installation on MacBook Air M1 chip. It drives me crazy. I get the error :
`zsh: command not found: vim`
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGv2z.png)

I enabled rosetta terminal and re-run it again, but same issue.
I tried almost all installation videos online but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `vim`. To install it, run the command below :

`sudo apt-get install vim`

You can also use `nano`. Also, it's `vim ~/.zshrc` (where ~/ refers to the home directory of the current user) and you also misspelled `zshrc`.

I suggest you follow the [official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) for the correct installation steps.

I have also created a detailed [blogpost](https://adityabhardwaj.dev/installing-flutter-correctly-in-macbook-big-sur/) about the installation steps and the possible issues that one might encounter. It is written extensively for MacBook Air with M1 chip running BigSur (which I work on).

Comment: I couldn't install it the error keep appears, can you do me a favour  by install it using team viewer software please .

Comment: I did literally the all steps you mentioned in your blog , but same various errors are showing . I gave up can you do it for me I will very appreciated.

Comment: brother can you please ?

Comment: @abdullahfarsi you could also share what went wrong and how you rectified it. May help others.

Comment: I simply imported the flutter SDK folder from android studio , that's it.